# Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type in sql server (Excluding the Static Values)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `table` storing starttime and endtime.

I Got

> Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime
>   data type.

Error while selecting below  query using that `table`.

```
select CAST(substring(CONVERT(varchar,convert(smalldatetime,o.StartTime),114), 1,2) as int) 
from TimeTable O
```

In analysis , I found out that Few Records with Starttime as `'9:30 PM'` causing the error. ( Other Records having  `'09:30 PM'` as start-time). I have excluded '9:30 PM' Records and query executed successfully.

The Problem Here is ,

If I explicitly specify the value in `select` statement as below,

```
SELECT CAST(substring(CONVERT(varchar,convert('9:30 PM',o.StartTime),114), 1,2) as int)
```

I didn't get any error.

But,  when I select from the `table` I got the error. can Anyone help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To what output your are actually looking for?

If you want the values like '9:30 PM' or '09:30 PM' to be converted as Time format, you can go ahead with the below one

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), '9:30 PM', 108)AS TIME)
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), '09:30 PM', 108)AS TIME)
```

Else if you want it to be stored in datetime or smalldatetime

then this will work for you

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), '9:30 PM', 108)AS DATETIME)
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), '09:30 PM', 108)AS DATETIME)
```